# RDLC - The tablix ‘Tablix13’ has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members

Tags: c#, reporting-services, report, reportviewer, rdlc

Here is how I make my report :

1. Add list to the body.
2. Add dataset fields to the list
3. Run the project.

And I get the error : 
The tablix ‘Tablix13’ has a detail member with inner members. Detail members can only contain static inner members.

How can I make my report list items without error? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this [SSRS Detail members can only contain static inner members.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7800217/ssrs-detail-members-can-only-contain-static-inner-members), delete delete group from main group and add parent group in second tablix.